# TinyMCE Package

Tags: c#, asp.net, tinymce, package

I am developing an article management system using asp.net 3.5 and c#.
I want to use the TinyMCE editor and want to write a plugin for choosing photos from a folder on the server.

Which Package/s do I need to download ?
"Main package" or "Development package" or ".NET package" or a combination of them ?

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/download.php

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are developing you will want the following:

Development Package - This has everything you need to set up plus some development tools and plugins that might make your life easier.

.Net Package - This gives you some additional .Net specific functionality and plugins. You need this in addition to the Development Package.

JQuery Package - If you want a JQuery enabled functionality you can load this. Like the .Net Package, this is an addon to the Development Package.

Compressor .Net - You will want this to zip all of the javascript files into a single file for faster streaming. This is optional but it is good to think about because TinyMCE creates a lot of javascript loading activies.

When you go to production you might want to consider switching out Development Package for Main Package, which is smaller and more compact but without all of the development addons for debugging purposes.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Tim for your detailed and informative answer to my question!

Comment: Please feel free to click on the little check directly below the number/arrows to the left of my post to accept it :) thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the direction (I am a new user of the site),I am more then happy to click and vote for your very good answer

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I think you'll find it very helpful.

Comment: There is one thing I did not understand :

If the creators of the packages intended that they can be used togther side by side (for example as you wrote Development Package + .Net Package + .Net Package)in the same web project, then why the downloaded zip files of the packages unzip to the same folder name : tinymce  ??? (there can't be more then one folder with that name in the root directory of the web project)

Comment: In TinyMCE web site Installation page ( http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Installation ) they wrote : "You should extract TinyMCE in your wwwroot or site domain root folder."
But as I wrote at the previous comment the different packages all
unzip to the same folder name.